# My website looks perfect on local host, but after uploading it online it looks completely different?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hyperlink, liveview

My website looks perfect on Dreamweaver live view, Google chrome but after uploading it online it looks completely different and I have no idea why?

I checked all the links but if it works on my local host then all the links should be right? The colour of the body on the web version isn't even set to be that originally?

Please help this is incredibly frustrating

The website that is online currently, uploaded through Plesk

[image]

The website that is tested on Live View/ Chrome etc

[image]

Comment: Please check the console in Chrome (open with F12) for any error messages.

Comment: Make sure that both web directories, the one on local host, and the one online have the EXACT same files. You could also be caching old css files etc. Try a reload without loading cache (ctrl+f5 in Chrome).

Comment: i thought CSS not loaded properly ! Please elaborate your console so we can help you.

Comment: I am currently reuploading the files just in case, if the links work on local host I don't know why they wouldn't once being uploaded to Plesk?What do you mean by console?

Comment: I redeleted all the files and uploaded them via file upload instead of dragging and dropping them into the file manager, why is this the case?

Comment: Open console (console firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console) in browser and post errors in your question. I guess (based on your screen shot) that your css files are not loaded. Ps : Console is your friend if you want to « build website »

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is problem in loading css file..

try adding version to css files..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=1.1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css?v=1.1">
```

and then try by just changing version from 1.1 to 1.2 onwards

Answer (score -1):

I found that my issue was coming up once I uploaded my web files on cpanel, I noticed that the permission settings were limited on my .css and bootstrap folder as compared to the .html files and img folder.. Adjusting the permissions instantly reflected changes on my live website